# Can a year-old oil-in-coolant situation fix itself?

Tags: cooling-system, buick, century, oil-in-coolant

So a year ago I took my 2003 Buick Century Custom to get an oil change.

The mechanic there told me he found oil in my cooling system and that I should start looking for a new car. I moved out of town and a year later (yesterday) I went back to them for another oil change.

However, this time the same mechanic said that everything looked fine except my front left wheel bearing needs to be replaced.

How does an issue as serious as he implied just simply go away? I fixed a small hose that was blown but that's it.

Comment: Did the mechanic even check the cooling system or did he just change the oil like he was supposed to? Not mentioning the problem doesn't mean its gone.

Comment: I specifically asked about the issue and it was definitely talked about but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It should be quite easy for you to verify if the problem still exists through a quick inspection of the coolant reservoir or radiator. Oil-contaminated coolant looks like chocolate milkshake and has a mayonnaise-like consistency to it.

Also, it is unrealistic to expect a mechanic to find or remember everything that is wrong with the vehicle, especially since a routine oil change doesn't require them to inspect the coolant reservoir.

Comment: Unrealistic sure I wont argue with you there. Its been a whole year! But thank you ill check it out.

Comment: This is a critical point here you bring up. Oil in the coolant does not necessarily imply there is coolant in the oil. If the mechanic was only changing the oil, there's no reason to assume he also inspected the coolant.

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment given being too new to the site.

This model has a common flaw with the intake gaskets. It's a straight-forward fix, and the solution is permanent. If the current gaskets are still Factory original, this is likely the cause of the issue.

The 3.1L is arguably one of GM's best engines.  I would recommend having the gaskets replaced, rather than getting rid of the car. The model tends to have some electrical issues, but other than that it's a very solid car.

I hope this helps.